# A task is related to a person. But how to get all tasks when we query _getPerson (id)?

Tags: entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Articles/Introduction-With-AspNet-Core-And-Entity-Framework-Core-Part-2/index.html

I have been following this aspnetboilerplate tutorial.
Every task is associated to a person using

```
    [ForeignKey(nameof(AssignedPersonId))]
    public Person AssignedPerson { get; set; }
    public Guid? AssignedPersonId { get; set; }
```

So in the get Query for tasks by doing an Include

> Include(t => t.AssignedPerson)

We can get the person assigned to this task

**However**

The requirement is to fetch a person & get all the tasks he is assigned to.

I under one solution would be adding `virtual List<Task> Tasks` property to the person class.

But I am now knowing whether to add this property to the entity class or the personDto.

Comment: Have you even tried?

Comment: Hi @aaron i will try to add this virtual navigation thing as mentioned in the other [tutorial](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Developing-MultiTenant-SaaS-ASP.NET-CORE-Angular/index.html) & if it works... i will answer this question myself or else will let you know..